# Regular expression or other get all elements names from a list

Tags: java, regex

I started with regular expression but for what I have found, I think is better to do it another way.

I want to get an array of the images name from the following text:

The following images failed:

```
[T430040.tif, T432040.tif, T411030.tif, CH1090.tif, T432050.tif, T432090.tif, T432020.tif, CRP040.tif, T432070.tif, T040060.tif]

Array:
T430040
T432040 
T411030
CH1090
T432050
T432090
T432020 
CRP040 
T432070 
T040060
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Why not use a *range-based* loop?...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This java code uses regex `\w+(?=\.)` does what you need.

```
String s = "The following images failed: [T430040.tif, T432040.tif, T411030.tif, CH1090.tif, T432050.tif, T432090.tif, T432020.tif, CRP040.tif, T432070.tif, T040060.tif]";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\w+(?=\\.)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
while(m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

And prints,

```
T430040
T432040
T411030
CH1090
T432050
T432090
T432020
CRP040
T432070
T040060
```

Comment: thanks Ill accept this as the answer as it takes more possibilities

Answer (score 2):

Without regex:

```
    String str = "The following images failed: [T430040.tif, T432040.tif, T411030.tif, CH1090.tif, T432050.tif, T432090.tif, T432020.tif, CRP040.tif, T432070.tif, T040060.tif]";
    String[] array = str.substring(str.indexOf("[") + 1, str.length() - 1)
            .replace(".tif", "")
            .split(",");
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
```

will print the array:

```
[T430040,  T432040,  T411030,  CH1090,  T432050,  T432090,  T432020,  CRP040,  T432070,  T040060]
```